# css div inheriting child's reverse margin

Tags: html, css

I know there's another question like this but I tried it and the answer didn't work.

I have a `p` with a `div` and I want to be able to use a reverse (negative) margin on the `p`.  At the moment it's not effecting the `p` but the containing `div`.

Here's the code :

```
.reset {
    margin-left:4px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background:#FFF;
}
.reset p {
    margin-top:-4px;
    font-size: 38px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you set up a jsFiddle. And its called negative margin not reverse margin for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because your `p` is the **first** element of your `div`. As a result, the margin-top of *both* your `p` and `div` are somewhat *merged*.

For example, if you put `margin-top: 20px` on both your `p` *and* your `div`, it will only result in a 20px top margin, not 40px.

The easiest way is to use `position: relative;`:

```
p { position: relative; top: -4px; }
```

This way, the `p` is still in the usual flow, but you move it 4px up.

Comment: The "merging" of margins is called *margin collapse*.

Comment: cimmanon: thanks. I always encountered this weird behavior but never knew how it was called.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of your whole solution, but setting the `div` to `relative`, and the `<p>` to `absolute` should get you in the right direction.  Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bfelda/xrdnQ/) to play with.

```
 .reset {
        margin-left:4px;
        margin-top: 4px;
        height:50px;
        width:50px;
        background:Silver;
        position: relative;

    }
    .reset p {
        position:absolute;
        margin-top:-4px;
        font-size: 38px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

[UPDATE]

A comment in another answer(now deleted) mentions that negative margins are not valid css.  To work with this, change the `.reset p` to:

```
.reset p {
    position:absolute;
    top: -4px; //or whatever you want
    left: 0px;  //or whatever you want
    font-size: 38px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Negative margins certainly are valid in CSS.

Comment: @cimmanon I thought so, thanks for verifying.  A now deleted answer stated this so I figured I'd provide options.